# Double buffered OpenGL objects in a consumer producer model

Tags: ios, multithreading, opengl-es

In my OpenGL iOS application I'm trying to implement the producer-consumer model where the producer needs to load the textures while the consumer needs to display them. From reading the documentation, I understand that this will require using an EAGL share group and that shared OpenGL objects should be double buffered. However, I'm not quite sure which OpenGL objects should be double buffered. Should the textures or the frambuffer? My producer loads three textures each time a new frame needs to be displayed therefore, I was thinking that might be more efficient to switch the framebuffer.

So, at high level this is what I was thinking it should happen:

1. Create one renderbuffer and two framebuffers (frameBuffers[2]) somewhere during openGL initialization.
2. In the producer thread, while the consumer thread is using frameBuffers[0], load the incoming frames as OpenGL textures onto frameBuffers[1] and push the framebuffer ID into some sort of shared queue.
3. In the consumer thread, pop the next frame buffer ID from the shared queue, and use it to bind the framebuffer (glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, i)). Finally swap the renderbuffer to display.

Does it make sense? Is there a better way to achieve all this?

Answer (score 0):

I presume since you're talking about loading new textures every frame you're not just grabbing them from disk. (For that, `GLKTextureLoader` provides an easy interface for asynchronous loading.)

You should use double buffering for the objects affected by the asynchronous part of your design. In this case, you're asynchronously loading textures, so the texture objects should be double-buffered. While your producer thread is loading textures 0, 1, and 2, your consumer thread can be drawing from textures 3, 4, and 5. So long as both operations complete in about the same amount of time, you can swap sets of buffers each frame; otherwise you'll need to look into triple buffering.